# Trimming strings between two points

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a string as follows:

```
ListViewSubItem: {Debian6/Debian6.vmx }
```

What would be the most efficient way of getting the following output:

```
Debian6/Debian6.vmx
```

Comment: Is efficiency a big issue? Or is it just a 'nice to have'?

Comment: Most efficient is: Substring(18,19)

Comment: Show your **ineffcient** way. We can try to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int beginidx = haystack.IndexOf('{');
string needle = haystack.SubString(beginidx,
                                   haystack.IndexOf('}') - beginidx + 1).Trim();
```

Comment: change to `haystack.IndextOf('{')` and to `haystack.IndexOf('}', beginidx + 1)` and it will be the best solution with no doubt.

Comment: @YoryeNathan my first answer used double quotes as the param, but changed to  single quotes (no compiler), thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
\{\s*(.*)\s*\}
```

The desired string will be in the first captured group (`Match.Groups[1]`).

Example:

```
string output = Regex.Match(input, @"\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}").Groups[1].Value;
```

As was pointed out, regexes are slower than plain string manipulation. If performance is an issue, and the string extraction is in a tight loop, then it may be better to use an optimized method. Otherwise, regex vs string is IMHO a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Regex will NOT be *most efficient*

Comment: It won't be significantly less efficient than string manipulation methods.

Comment: 1. It will be. 2. "Most" means "most", not "more or less".

Comment: It will be?  I highly doubt that.

Comment: If the regex is precompiled, the string manipulation is about 5 times faster.

Comment: I fixed a bug in the regex. Now it's 3 times slower than before. :(

Answer (score 0):

`string result = Regex.Match("ListViewSubItem: {Debian6/Debian6.vmx }", @"(?<={)(.+?)(?=})").Value;`

Comment: Regex will NOT be most efficient

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you didn't generate that string yourself.  So the question is, why parse it? This looks like the sort of question where you should take a step back and think of what you're trying to solve, and if another method might be cleaner.

I am not familiar with the `ListViewSubItem` class, but it seems like you have one of these and you have called `ToString()` on it.  Now you are parsing the output of `ToString()` to see the model object your sub-item represents.

Does this not seem backwards to you?  Maybe you should deal with the `ListViewSubItem` object itself (from a brief look at the documentation, what you want seems to be the `Text` property), rather than fiddling with what `ToString()` returns, which seems volatile and dependent on the implementation of that class's `ToString()` method (which, though likely not, could theoretically change from release to release).  Not to mention corner cases like "what if the string contains the `}` character?"

For this in other reasons, as a general rule I think you should not have to deal with serialization when your data source is in memory the whole time.

So, in summary, if you have something like this:

```
  ListViewSubItem item = /* ... */;

  string s = item.ToString();

  // TODO: parse {Debian} out of ListViewSubItem {Debian}
```

Why not this instead:

```
  ListViewSubItem item = /* ... */;

  string OS = item.Text;
```